# adjacency matrix vs list memory efficient

Tags: data-structures, graph

if graph is complete graph that have self roof, i think adjacency matrix`s memory is more efficient than adjacency list.
is it right?

In my opinion, when it's a sparse matrix, the adjacent list is memory-efficient, but when it's a density matrix, I hope there's a concrete basis for using adjacent matrices.

Comment: Yes, if you know that the graph is complete, an adjacency matrix is almost certainly a better choice than an adjacency list.

Comment: i agree your opinion, but What I want to know is the memory difference when graph is complete

Answer (score 1):

An adjacency matrix requires one bit of storage for every possible edge.  This is optimal if about half of all possible edges are actually in the graph, because there are about 2<sup>|V|<sup>2</sup></sup> such configurations.

If you know that the graph is complete, then you only need to store that fact, because it tells you exactly what the adjacency matrix would be.

If you know that the graph is almost complete, then you can store, for each vertex, a list of vertices that are *not* its neighbors, and that will be smaller than an adjacency matrix.

The concept of how compactly you can store data depending on what you know about it (its statistics) is referred to as "[entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))" in information theory, since it is closely analogous to the same-named concept in physics.

Comment: Great answer! I suggest being more explicit about "you only need to store that fact"; maybe something like "you don't need to store the adjacency matrix at all"